# JIRA Rest API DELETE call for removing user/actor is not removing users

Tags: java, rest, httpclient, jira, jira-rest-api

We are using REST APIs to remove users from the actor roles of Projects.
We are using DELETE call for removing user/actor from the roles from a project.

JIRA call (Delete)
https:///rest/api/2/project/11264/role/10100?user=

REST API referring to,
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.0.10/#api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}/role-deleteActor

The API returns 204 status message, but the user/actor is not removed from the Project.
I have tried this using JAVA, REST Clients

Has anyone experience this behaviour. If yes, could you please guide me on this.

Comment: Try using postman to with the rest api and see if you get back the results.
https://www.getpostman.com/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too and submitted a support request to Atlassian. They told me the delete actor endpoint uses the user_key which is the lowercase version of the first username the user ever had.

Check the fault report at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-68189 for more detail.

The userkey can be found for a username by calling /rest/api/2/user?username= which includes the key in its response.

Comment: It's now fixed in Jira Server 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

your call should be like this

```
https:/<JIRA_URL>/rest/api/2/project/<Project-KEY>/role/10100?user=<username>
```

eg.

```
https://myjira.uat.com:8443/rest/api/2/project/SAND/role/10700?user=amitraj
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jira always returns 204 regardless if user is removed or not, sadly.

Unfortunately, in some cases, the user is not removed (altough projectKey, roleId and userName are definitely correct. This happens approx. for 1/20 calls and I don't why.

To make sure if the user has been really deleted I run another API call to check project role members after deletion:

```
/rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}/role/{id}
```

I'm running Jira 7.3.6 and using REST API with Python.

Not sure if removing users using ScriptRunner and Groovy would be better but I don't want to rewrite whole script into a different environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one user, and I just noticed that passing a lowercase username does work (JIRA+Crowd in our setup). Always using lowercase should be fine according to the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowd/case-sensitivity-of-usernames-and-groups-181536383.html), though it should work in all cases.